# Meaning of "." in printf

Tags: c

I was just reading the classic K&R and encountered the following syntax:

```
printf("%.*s",max,s);
```

What is the meaning of `"."` here?When I don't apply a `"."` here,then whole string is printed,but when we don't apply a `"."` ,atmost max characters are printed.I will be really thankful if anyone could explain this.

Comment: Have you read the C standard? It specifies how this should work...

Comment: @DCoder Having worked with the C standard a lot I am positive that it's not possible to *read* it.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: that may be true for certain *parts* of the standard, but I find the section describing `printf` to be quite readable.

Comment: ignoring the standard, man printf gives a good description on most machines.

Comment: Note that on StackOverflow, once an issue has been resolved to the asker's satisfaction, he or she is [expected to accept the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). The purpose of this is both to provide a symbolic reward to the volunteer who took the time to write an answer, and to give future visitors insight in the most correct solution, as judged by the asker.

Comment: Plonk. How nice would it be if the OP accepted one of those answers. After almost four months. Sigh. Can I downvote users? 8O

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `%.*s`, the `.*` limits the number of bytes that will be written. If this were written with a numeral included, such as `%.34s`, then the numeral would be the limit. When an asterisk is used, the limit is taken from the corresponding argument to `printf`.

From C 2011 (N1570) 7.21.6.1 4, describing conversion specifications for `fprintf` *et al*:

> An optional precision that gives … the maximum number of bytes to be written for **s** conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (**.**) followed either by an asterisk ***** (described later) or by an optional decimal integer; if only the period is specified, the precision is taken as zero.

Comment: You might want to write, "in `%.*s`, the part `.*` limits ..." otherwise it's kind of hard to read.

Comment: I'd replace 'numeral' with 'integer' or 'number'.

Comment: @Veltas: Thanks, I insert “the” before `.*`. Regarding numerals and numbers, integers and numbers are mathematical objects. A numeral is symbols (particularly a string of digits) that denotes a number. So “34” is a numeral and is not a number, the same way “wolf” is a word and is not an animal.

Answer (score 13):

It specifies the "Character String Maximum field width"

The precision within a string format specifies the maximum field width:

`%2.6s`

specifies a minimum width of 2 and a maximum width of 6 characters. If the string is greater than 6 characters, it will be truncated.

Answer (score 4):

A printf format string allows specifying width and precision.

Width, such as `%25s`, tells `printf` to pad the string to the width of 25 characters, inserting spaces before the string. (If the string is wider than 25 characters, it is still printed in its entirety.)

A "precision" applied to a string format, such as `%.25s`, limits the length of the printed string to 25 characters. A string of 3 characters will be printed fully (with no padding), and a string of 30 characters will be missing its last five characters.

`%.*s` avoids hardcoding the precision in the format, specifying it instead as an integer argument to `printf`, in your case `max`.

Comment: "Not known at the time format is written," what does this mean?

Comment: @Veltas When you write a format such as `%.25s`, you know that you'll need precision of 25 characters. When you write `%.*s`, you leave the precision undetermined until run-time. I'll try to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, K&R is the original implementation of C, which is different from the current specification. If you want specific information about K&R C, then consult specific documentation.

From the current C standard:

> An optional precision that gives (...) the maximum number of bytes to be written for s conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed either by an asterisk * (described later) or by an optional decimal integer.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Similar documentation is available everywhere online for multiple standards or implementations:

- glibc
  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Output-Conversion-Syntax.html#Output-Conversion-Syntax
- POSIX
  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html
- Microsoft C runtime
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Dot has different meaning with different format strings . If you use a.b with %f , then b gives length . a gives number of decimal points . if you use a.b with %s , a will give minimum length of the string . whereas b gives maximum length of the string that will be printed .

Answer (score 0):

It actually print the character in limited number and commanded format based on the function passed to printf,in this case it should print the specific  of "max"